# Is there an equivalent of small claims court in Switzerland (Basel canton)?

Tags: small-claims-court, switzerland

I'm in Switzerland, and I'm involved in a dispute over about 300 Swiss francs.  I can anticipate needing to take it to court.

In the US, there exists "small claims court" where, instead of the time and expense of a full civil trial with lawyers and a jury, the two parties tell their stories to a judge, who makes a ruling immediately.

Does such a thing exist in Switzerland?  (Specifically I'm in the Basel-Stadt canton.)

Comment: It may depend on what it is about. As a renter, there is a "Schlichtungsstelle", in german: https://www.mietberatung.bs.ch/